# Getting nested forms to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I'm trying to build a nested form, but the nested form of question_fields isn't rendering in the browser.  That form has a nested form called answers, also not rendering

Here's the nested form, _createpoll.html.haml

```
= form_for Poll.new, :class=>'create-poll-form', :remote => true do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "Poll Title"
  = f.text_field :description, :placeholder => 'Description'

  / Required accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions in the polls model.  
  = f.fields_for :questions do |builder| 
    = render "questions/question_fields", :f => builder

  = f.submit "Create Poll", :class => 'btn btn-danger'
```

Here's the _questions_fields.html.haml:

```
%p
  = f.label :content, "Question"
  = f.text_area :content
  = f.check_box :_destroy
  = f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question"
%p
  = f.fields_for :answers do |builder|
    = render "answers/answer_fields", :f => builder
```

Here's the related Polls Controller, new and create actions

```
  def create
    @poll = Poll.create(params[:poll])
  end

  def new
    @poll = Poll.new  
    1.times do
      question = @poll.questions.build
      2.times {question.answers.build}
    end
  end
```

Any ideas on why this might not be rendering?  Thanks in advance for the tips!!

**Update, a new question**

After creating the poll with its associated questions and answers, after querying the database, I see that that the foreign keys aren't persisted and the association is lost.  Do I have to use hidden fields here somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Silly oversight.  Poll.new has to be @poll... whoops.

**Updating Answer.**

This form was was rendered by a button on the user's dashboard, "Create Poll," routing through the controller's new action.

As controller's new action instantiates the new poll, I was being redundant when instantiating another poll in the `form for`.  By switching this to the newly created instance variable `@poll`, the form rendered.  Also, `:content` threw a no method error, but that's because it wasn't in the `attr_accessible` of the questions or answers models.

Comment: @Keith - Sounds like you may have figured out the problem yourself? If so, good job :) However, could you elaborate a little? Just so people do not mistake it for a comment or non-answer.

Comment: @Leigh Just updated it.  Let me know if you have more questions, sorry about the lack of clarity!